# How do I remove empty data frames from a list?

Tags: r

I've got dozens of lists, each is a collection of 11 data frames. Some data frames are empty (another script did not output any data, not a bug).

I need to push each list through a function but that chokes when it sees an empty data frame.  So how do I write a function that will take a list, do a dim on each element (i.e. data frame) and if it's 0, then skip to the next.

I tried something like this:

```
empties <- function (mlist)
{
 for(i in 1:length(mlist))
   {
    if(dim(mlist[[i]])[1]!=0) return (mlist[[i]])
    }
}
```

But clearly, that didn't work. I would do this manually at this point but that would take forever. Help?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but if you want to trim `mlist` down to contain only non-empty data frames before running the function on it, try `mlist[sapply(mlist, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]`.

E.g.:

```
R> M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
R> M2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))
R> M3 <- data.frame(matrix(9:12, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
R> mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)
R> mlist[sapply(mlist, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]
[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  1  3
2  2  4

[[2]]
  X1 X2
1  9 11
2 10 12
```

Comment: What about a nested list? Would I have to loop it?

Answer (score 18):

A slightly simpler and more transparent approach to the sapply/indexing combination is to use the Filter() function:

```
> Filter(function(x) dim(x)[1] > 0, mlist)
[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  1  3
2  2  4

[[2]]
  X1 X2
1  9 11
2 10 12
```

Comment: Any idea on what might be better performing?

Comment: @TMOTTM, they should be almost exactly the same, I think. (But try it and let us know if not!)

Comment: `nrow(x) > 0` instead of `dim(x)[1] > 0`.  Less is more

Comment: What about a nested list? Would I have to loop it?

Comment: From review: some anonymous editor suggest that: you should try `Filter(function(x) length(x) > 0, mlist)`, it performs much better.

Comment: @SergGr That won't work, I think. `length()` applied to a `data.frame` gets the number of _columns_, not _rows_. (Because a `data.frame` is a list with some metadata, and `length` operates on lists.) So that filter will only work if by "empty" the original poster meant "no columns", which is a thing that can happen, but probably not what was meant...

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `dim(x)[1]` you could make use of `nrow`, so you could do

```
mlist[sapply(mlist, nrow) > 0]

Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 0, mlist)
```

You could also use `keep` and `discard` from `purrr`

```
purrr::keep(mlist, ~nrow(.) > 0)
purrr::discard(mlist, ~nrow(.) == 0)
```

There is also `compact` in `purrr` which removes all empty elements directly. It is a wrapper on `discard`

```
purrr::compact(mlist)
```

If you are ok to filter the list based on number of columns, you could replace `nrow` with `ncol` in above answers. Additionally, you could also use `lengths` to filter the list.

```
mlist[lengths(mlist) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding tidyverse option:

```
library(tidyverse)
mlist[map(mlist, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]


mlist[map(mlist, ~dim(.)[1]) > 0]
```