# How do I replace empty dataframe/data.tables from a list with a placeholder data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, apply, lapply

This post [How do I remove empty data frames from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261452/how-do-i-remove-empty-data-frames-from-a-list) talks about removing empty dataframes. How do i remove empty dataframes(nrow =0) from a list and replace them with 1 row placeholder dataframes/data.tables?

```
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(9:12, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)

placeholder  = data.table(a=1,b=1)
```

I tried:

```
lapply(mlist, function(x) ifelse(nrow(fundslist[[x]]) == 0, placeholder, x))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be using `lengths`

```
mlist[!lengths(mlist)] <- list(placeholder)
str(mlist)
#List of 3
# $ :'data.frame':       2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ X1: int [1:2] 1 2
#  ..$ X2: int [1:2] 3 4
# $ :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':      1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ a: num 1
#  ..$ b: num 1
#  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
# $ :'data.frame':       2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ X1: int [1:2] 9 10
#  ..$ X2: int [1:2] 11 12
```

Comment: Oh, `lengths`, I somehow missed that one. This is clearly a superior solution to anything posted so far as it uses recycling of a list.

Comment: A minor point: I often have "empty" data.tables that just have no observations (nrow of zero, like in the OP) and yet do have columns, looking like `DT = data.table(a=1)[0L]`. So testing for that case, `!sapply(mlist, nrow)`.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I thought about that case.  Yours is more general.

Comment: @Frank  That was actually my case too, I have empty data tables with nrow of zero but with columns, my OP presents a slight variation of the problem.So `!sapply(mlist, nrow)` came in very handy. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How about this? Since your placeholder is fairly small, it's not a problem to multiply it n times.

```
library(data.table)

M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(9:12, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)

placeholder  = data.table(a=1,b=1)

num.rows <- unlist(lapply(mlist, nrow))
num.zeros <- length(num.rows[num.rows == 0])
replacement <- replicate(num.zeros, {placeholder}, simplify = FALSE)

mlist[num.rows == 0] <- replacement

str(mlist)

List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X1: int [1:2] 1 2
  ..$ X2: int [1:2] 3 4
 $ :Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ a: num 1
  ..$ b: num 1
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X1: int [1:2] 9 10
  ..$ X2: int [1:2] 11 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain how you could complete it using your approach itself!

```
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 0))
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(9:12, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)

placeholder  = data.frame(matrix(c(1,1), nrow=1))

abc <- function(x){
  if(sum(dim(x))==0)
    return(data.frame(placeholder))
  else
    return(x)
}

lapply(mlist, abc)
```