# Remove NA value within a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na

I'm sure there is a very easy answer to this but I can't find one. In a separate post, [How do I remove empty data frames from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261452/how-do-i-remove-empty-data-frames-from-a-list) I have looked at removing an empty data frame from a list of data frames.

But how can you do this when one of the items in the list isn't classified as a data frame and is just a NA value? Modifying the parameters of the question above slightly, you have:

```
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M2 <- NA
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(9:12, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)
```

I would like to remove M2 in this instance, but I have several examples of these empty data frames so I would like a function that removes them all simultaenously.

I have tried a couple of solutions to the question above which do not work:

```
mlist[sapply(mlist, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]##Error message -
##Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Filter(function(x) dim(x), mlist) ###Incorrect outputs
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Like so `Filter(is.data.frame, mlist)`?

Comment: `mlist[!is.na(mlist)]` ?

Comment: Both work perfectly thank you! If one of you would like to put your answer below I will tick it.

Comment: `NA` is not an empty data.frame. `data.frame()` is an empty data.frame. `NA` is a missing value.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the title of the question and text accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `Filter` to check wheter the list elements are `data.frame`s

```
Filter(is.data.frame, mlist)
#[[1]]
#  X1 X2
#1  1  3
#2  2  4

#[[2]]
#  X1 X2
#1  9 11
#2 10 12
```

Comment: @AndreElrico I see OP changed the title. Wasn't sure wheter the question was about `data.frames` or `NA`s.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different way to get your result

```
library(tidyverse)

M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M2 <- NA
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(9:12, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M4 <- NA
mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3,M4)

indexes <- tibble()

for (i in 1:length(mlist)) {

  if (is.na(mlist[[i]]) == TRUE) {

    new_index <- tibble(index = i)

    indexes <- bind_rows(new_index,indexes)

  }
}

indexnums <- indexes %>% pull(index)

mlist <- mlist[-indexnums]
```

With this, you check if each list element is NA or not, then add the index number to a table if it is, then you pull those index numbers out and subset the list. If you have a lot of these in your data set this should remove them all.

Answer (score 1):

Hope to help you.

```
# Method 1
mlist[!is.na(mlist)]

# Method 2
replace(mlist, is.na(mlist), NULL)
```