# Extract dataframes from a large list based on matching values given by another dataframe

Tags: r, filtering

I am new to R and despite having researched the site I can't seem to solve this:

I have a very large list of dataframes (of historical climate data from different sites) and I need to make a new list that would only contain those dataframes with specific values (longitudes and latitudes) given by one independent dataframe.

So I have:

```
df1 <- data.frame("x" = c(1, 1, 1), "y" = c(-2, -2, -2), "a" = c(3, 6, 9), "b" = c(4, 5, 3))
df2 <- data.frame("x" = c(1.2, 1.2, 1.2), "y" = c(-2, -2, -2), "a" = c(3, 4, 78), "b" = c(12, 5, 8))
df3 <- data.frame("x" = c(1.3, 1.3, 1.3), "y" = c(-2.1, -2.1, -2.1), "a" = c(19, 5, 5), "b" = c(7, 7, 20))

my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Each dataframe corresponds to one site, with a specific value of lon and lat given in two columns (constant value for all row length, since it's the same site)

```
> df1
  x  y a b
1 1 -2 3 4
2 1 -2 6 5
3 1 -2 9 3  
> df2
    x  y  a  b
1 1.2 -2  3 12
2 1.2 -2  4  5
3 1.2 -2 78  8
> df3
    x    y  a  b
1 1.3 -2.1 19  7
2 1.3 -2.1  5  7
3 1.3 -2.1  5 20
```

Then, I have an independent dataframe with longitudes and latitudes that I will like to obtain the climate data for.

```
df_xy <- data.frame("x"= c(1, 1.3), "y" = c(-2, -2.1))
> df_xy
    x    y
1 1.0 -2.0
2 1.3 -2.1
```

Ideally I would obtain a new list with the dataframes that match the x, y specified.

```
output_list <- list(df1, df3)
```

As much as I have tried with lapply and Map(merge, my_list, df_xy) I can't seem to make it work out. Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do: 
`output_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x) merge(x, df_xy))`

In `output_list`, the second list will be empty.

Optionally, based on [How do I remove empty data frames from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261452/how-do-i-remove-empty-data-frames-from-a-list), you could then disregard empty dataframes from `output_list` using `Filter(function(x) dim(x)[1], output_list)`

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!